# Passing a Structure by reference to a function that will dynamically create and fill a array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, data-structures

I want to pass a structure pointer to a function that will dynamically create a array of structures at the location pointed to by the structure pointer that was passed. I am able to create and fill the array of structure successfully but when trying to print the data in the calling function using the pointer that was passed gives me a garbage values. Please help me know why my structure pointer is pointing to garbage and how can I access my data correctly.

The following is just some example code to demonstrate how the structure is passed and dynamically filled using malloc & realloc. this is INCORRECT method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student 
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    float percentage;
};

void func(struct student *record);

int main() 
{
    struct student *record = NULL;

    record = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));

    func(record);

    if(record != NULL)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            printf(" 1 Id is: %d \n", record[i].id);
            printf(" 1 Name is: %s \n", record[i].name);
            printf(" 1 Percentage is: %f \n", record[i].percentage);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("record pointer is null");
    }

    return 0;
}

void func(struct student *record1)
{
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        if(i)
        {
            record1 = (struct student *)realloc(record1,sizeof(struct student)*(i+1));
        }
        record1[i].id=1;
        strcpy(record1[i].name, "Raju");
        record1[i].percentage = 86.5;
    }
}
```

The following is a similar example using double pointer which is the CORRECT way to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student 
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    float percentage;
};

void func(struct student **record);

int main() 
{
    struct student *record = NULL;

    func(&record);

    if(record != NULL)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            printf(" 1 Id is: %d \n", record[i].id);
            printf(" 1 Name is: %s \n", record[i].name);
            printf(" 1 Percentage is: %f \n", record[i].percentage);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("record pointer is null");
    }

    free(record);

    return 0;
}

void func(struct student **record1)
{
    *record1 = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        if(i)
        {
            *record1 = (struct student *)realloc(*record1,sizeof(struct student)*(i+1));
        }
        (*record1)[i].id=1;
        strcpy((*record1)[i].name, "Raju");
        (*record1)[i].percentage = 86.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you program in C++ why do you use `malloc` and `free` and `realloc`? The "correct" solution here is to use `std::vector<TEST_STRUCT>`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am mostly trying for a C based solution but if needed I could also work with C++ concepts, I will look into vectors.

Comment: @O'Neil Since there were a bunch of issues with the example I had posted I replaced it with to new simpler examples one of which is working. So since you mentioned that ap_test is a copy of my pointer test, then If I need it to point to the same location as the original pointer what should I do. I have tried using Double Pointer but I am getting Debug Assertion Failure message. Surprisingly in the new example I have provided it is working even with the copy of the pointer.

Comment: `record1`  => `*record1` within `realloc`. It's less error prone to use a temporary pointer to do all the stuff, and eventually assign `*record1 = that_pointer;`. About the surprising copy result, I guess realloc didn't change the adress while reallocating.

Comment: @O'Neil Your last suggestion worked for me, you should post this as a answer and I will mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Additionally, don't cast `malloc` and `realloc` for no reason. `if(i)` when you are looping through `i` from `0` to `1`, and `realloc` only if `i` is not zero, there has to be a better and efficient way of doing it.

Comment: @O'Neil make sure you explain in your write-up why passing `struct student *record` does not work. How the addresses for `record` are separate and distinct between `main` and `func` and why passing the *address of* `record` is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first solution,

```
record1 = (struct student *)realloc(record1,sizeof(struct student)*(i+1));
```

works *as long as realloc does not have to move the pointer!* That is, realloc just expands the memory area it gave earlier to `record1`. Should, at some later stage, `realloc` be required to give you another piece of memory, then the earlier pointer `record` in `main` will become *invalid* and could now contain your "garbage".

As you were thinking, you need a double pointer to be able to see the changed pointer in `main`. You were nearly there, just a typo:

```
*record1 = (struct student *)realloc(record1,sizeof(struct student)*(i+1));
```

in the above line the second occurrence of `record1` must also be dereferenced, so `*record1` because you must give `realloc` the original pointer.

Oh, and *don't* cast the result of malloc! Although the compiler does not complain, it can cause future problems.

Comment: can you tell me why casting malloc is bad. Also when I try to remove the type cast in my second example and compile the code I get the error message: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "student *". So how do I avoid type casting the return value of malloc in my case.

Comment: @Ghos3t: Thats a different question, and it already has a great answer. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/4228131), and the accepted answer.

Comment: Good reference from WedaPashi. But when your compiler complains about that void pointer, then you are compiling as C++, not as C.